# UIApplication get name of app which will handle URL

Tags: ios, uiapplicationdelegate, uiapplication, openurl

Is it possible to retrieve the name of the app which will handle a specific URL?

In other apps I saw "Open Link in Safari" and if you click, YouTube or whatever else will launch. I don't really like this behavior and I'd like the get the corresponding app name before calling

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL someURL]];`

to set the right button title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible with the official SDK.

If you really want that you could create a file/database with the most common URL schemes on iOS (check [this](http://handleopenurl.com)), then ship your app with it.